# Are there "gaps" between Lipschitz functions and $C^1$ functions?

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering about this fact. By Rademacher theorem, it is well known that a Lipschitz function in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is $\mathcal{L}^d$-a.e. differentiable. Of course, a $C^1$ function is everywhere differentiable with continuity by definiton. My question is: are there any "reasonable sets" of functions that lie in between in terms of differentiability? By reasonable set I mean a set of functions that can be defined in some way (not just any random counterexample) and with which one can work with, maybe having some compactness property. For instance, a Sobolev-like class of functions that are not only $\mathcal{L}^d$-a.e. differentiable, but $\mathcal{H}^{d-1}$-a.e., or something like that.

EDIT: Ok, $C^1$ does not imply Lipschitz as pointed out in the comments, but that's not the point (consider a $C^1$ function on a closed ball or whatever makes it Lipschitz). The point is if there are reasonable classes of functions not differentiable everywhere but in "more points" than, say, Lipschitz or Sobolev functions.

Comment: How about "differentiable functions"?

Comment: @MikhailKatz [Differentiable does not imply Lipschitz](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2048334).

Comment: @NikWeaver, $C^1$ mentioned by OP does not imply Lipshitz, either.  Obviously I meant "differentiable *and* Lipshitz".

Comment: Possibly of interest are the comments to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4385935/13130).